# Create an EventBridge Rule that triggers a Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-event-bridge

The code below is what I am using to create an EventBridge rule that will trigger a lambda function (specified by lambdaARN) on a specific time (cron_schedule).

```
async createEventBridgeLambdaTrigger(
    name: string,
    target: string,
    cron_schedule: string,
    lambdaARN: string,
    lambdaInput: Object
  ): Promise<string> {

    // Create the Event Bridge Rule
    const params = {
      Name: name,
      ScheduleExpression: `cron(${cron_schedule})`,
      State: "ENABLED",
    };
    const command = new PutRuleCommand(params);
    try {
      const response = await this.client.send(command);

      // Create the Target to hook to the lambda
      const params2 = {
        Rule: name,
        Targets: [
          {
            Arn: lambdaARN,
            Id: target,
            Input: JSON.stringify(lambdaInput),
          },
        ],
      };
      const command2 = new PutTargetsCommand(params2);
      await this.client.send(command2);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

The code is successfully creating the EventBridge rule and target, and is correctly targeting the lambda I want. Everything seems fine, the only problem is that the lambda is not being triggered.

One solution that occurred to me was to manually add the eventBridge as a trigger to the Lambda function, but I want to do it programmatically.

My use case is the following:

1. User sends a date, in which he wants a specific action to be triggered.
2. The calls a lambda function that will run the code above, successfully creating an EventBridge rule and target.
3. At the date given, the EventBridge rule should be triggered and it should invoke the (other) lambda function with the given 'lambdaInput' as parameter.

The only part not working is the triggering part.

NB: I am using serverless to deploy my cloudformation

Answer (score 0):

Did some research, and according to AWS:

> Permissions Note: When using the EventBridge console, EventBridge will
> automatically configure the proper permissions for the selected
> targets. If you're using the AWS CLI, SDK, or CloudFormation, you'll
> need to configure the proper permissions.

Therefore, I had to add the correct permissions for it to invoke my lambda since I was not using the console.

This code using the @aws-sdk/client-lambda worked like a charm:

```
async addLambdaPermission(
    eventSourceArn: string, // ARN of the EventBridgeRule
    functionArn: string, // ARN of the invoked Lambda
    name: string         // Name of the EventBridgeRule
  ) {
    const params: AddPermissionCommandInput = {
      FunctionName: functionArn,
      StatementId: name,
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      Principal: "events.amazonaws.com",
      SourceArn: eventSourceArn,
    };
    const command = new AddPermissionCommand(params);
    try {
      await this.lambda.send(command);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Adding Permission Error: ", error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
```